# После перезапуска приложения не сохраняется выбранный язык

Tags: java, android, смена-языка

В моём приложении я хочу добавить функцию смены языка, независимо от глобального, для этого я добавил кнопки, на который назначил следующий функционал.

```
        cv_language_en.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            Locale locale = new Locale("en");
            Locale.setDefault(locale);
            Configuration config = getBaseContext().getResources().getConfiguration();
            config.locale = locale;
            getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,
                    getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
            onBackPressed();
        });

        cv_language_ru.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            Locale locale = new Locale("ru");
            Locale.setDefault(locale);
            Configuration config = getBaseContext().getResources().getConfiguration();
            config.locale = locale;
            getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,
                    getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
            onBackPressed();
        });

        cv_language_ua.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            Locale locale = new Locale("uk");
            Locale.setDefault(locale);
            Configuration config = getBaseContext().getResources().getConfiguration();
            config.locale = locale;
            getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,
                    getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
            onBackPressed();
        });
```

Всё работает, только вот при перезапуске приложения, выбранный язык не сохраняется и запускается на системном, как сделать так что бы после перезапуска приложения, язык который выбрал пользователь, сохранялся?

Comment: Язык устанавливается не навсегда, а только на время работы приложения. Вы должны "запомнить" выбранный язык (например в `SharedPreferences`) и применять его при каждом запуске.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По совету @woesss я использовал SharedPreferences, но немного изменил структуру кодировки.

```
public class ActivityLanguage extends BackStackActivity {

    CardView back_lang, cv_language_en, cv_language_ru, cv_language_ua;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        loadLocale();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_language);

        back_lang = findViewById(R.id.back_language);
        back_lang.setOnClickListener(v -> onBackPressed());

        cv_language_en = findViewById(R.id.cv_language_en);
        cv_language_ru = findViewById(R.id.cv_language_ru);
        cv_language_ua = findViewById(R.id.cv_language_ua);


        cv_language_en.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            setLanguage("en");
            onBackPressed();
        });

        cv_language_ru.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            setLanguage("ru");
            onBackPressed();
        });

        cv_language_ua.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            setLanguage("uk");
            onBackPressed();
        });
    }

    public void setLanguage(String language) {
        Locale locale = new Locale(language);
        Locale.setDefault(locale);
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        configuration.locale = locale;
        getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(configuration, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("Settings", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
        editor.putString("My_Lang", language);
        editor.apply();
    }

    public void loadLocale() {
        SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("Settings", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String language = preferences.getString("My_Lang", "");
        setLanguage(language);
    }


    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityLanguage.this, ActivitySettings.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fragment_fade_enter, R.anim.fragment_fade_exit);
    }
}
```